# LND: How to use whole UTXO to open a channel?

Tags: utxo, lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels

How can I use an UTXO completely to open a Channel? Do I have to calculate the fees by hand to do this? If so, what would it be if I have a 1 million sat UTXO and set fees to 3sat/vB?